# Change View based on Option selected in select_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to make a form where a user can wither post normally with their username like this - > normal

```
  =form_for @confession , html: {multipart: true} do |f|
    =f.label :Confess
    =f.text_area :confession , require: true
    =f.file_field :confessionimage
    =f.select (:id,options_for_select(ID))
    =f.submit 'Confess'
```

or Anonymously where their Names will be hidden and no one will know that who posted this post .. for this what I thought was I will make a user named anonymous in database and if a user select anonymous in select_form while posting they will post as an anonymous user.

for this in my controller I want something like this and main point that I can't understand is how can the controller know what user has selected ?

this is my controller

```
    def index 
       @amitian = Amitian.where(institute: current_amitian.institute) if                 amitian_signed_in?
       @confessions = Confession.where(amitian_id: @amitian.ids).order('created_at   DESC') if amitian_signed_in?
       @confession = current_amitian.confessions.build 
       @anonymous = Amitian.where(email: anonymous@anonymous.com)
       # (if anonymous selected )
       do @anonymous.confessions.build   
    end
```

Comment: form data will be available in params hash

Comment: can u plz explain in answer with code snippet

Comment: I hope your actual indentation is a lot more orderly than what's here because this is all over the place. Clean code is readable code, and readable code makes it easier to find bugs.

Comment: obviously this is haml i have properly indented code... but that's not what i have asked can you plz help me with the ans

Comment: just tell me how can i access f.select element using params[:postid] rest i will fig out , in my controller how will i know whether user has selected anonymous or his name

Answer (score 0):

To access this :id params you use `confession_params[:id]`, or `params[:confession][:id]`
If you want to conditionally load different views you could use a respond_to block like this:

```
if confession_params[:id] == 1 #or params[:confession][:id] == 1
  loaded_view = :foo
else
  loaded_view = :bar
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render loaded_view }
end
```

This would load `foo.html.erb` or `bar.html.erb`, based on you `@confession` `:id` parameter, passed by your select on `form_for` tag, which loads parameter names based on your view's variable model.

Comment: by [:id ] you mean [:confession][:postid]  i.e  [:tablename][:attribute]  ryt ?

Comment: I tried this in my code

@ anonymous.each do |a|

 @ debug = a

 if params[:confession][:postid] == 'Anonymous'

  @ confession = a.confessions.build

 else
  @ confession = current_amitian.confessions.build 

and got the error = undefined method '[]' for nil:Nillclass

Comment: You are using non-standard params then. Try to read the logs of the request, it will print the params sent with it's identifiers.

Comment: It would be something like:
    `Processing by Auto::SitemapController#group as XML
       Parameters: {"group"=>"potal_grand_brasil"}` In this case the only parameter is `params[:group]`, you should identify which is the one you need

Comment: You could also do a `p params` to see what is passed, or use some debugging tool like `byebug`, if you can't find your way into logs